# Integer modulus division and integer division remainder with Ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina, wso2-esb

How to do,

1. integer modulus division and
2. integer division remainder

operations with **Ballerina**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the modulus by using `/` operator and remainder using `%` operator.

Check the following code:

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    int i = 10;
    int j = 3;

    int x = i / j;
    int y = i % j;

    io:println("i / j = " + x.toString());
    io:println("i % j = " + y.toString());
}
```

This will result the following:

```
i / j = 3
i % j = 1
```

Comment: Can we add this content to Ballerina by guide?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've created an issue for this. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/19434